# NullPointerException in TestCode when using restTemplate and jparepository

Tags: java

Here is my Code

NullPointerException occurs in using restTemplate and postsRepository.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class PostsApiControllerTest {
@LocalServerPort
private int port;

@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
private PostsRepository postsRepository;

@Test
public void register_posts() throws Exception{
    // ...

    ResponseEntity<Long> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,requestDto,Long.class);

    List<Posts> all = postsRepository.findAll();
}
```

Comment: Can you show me your pom.xml? Make sure that the spring-boot-starter-test is included in your POM.

Comment: Try  `@Mock` instead of  `@autowired` on repository and resttemplate var